# POSIX C `warning: variable ‘tables’ set but not used`

Tags: c, linux, posix

I wrote a code, everything ok, compiles and works without a problem, when I compile it with GCC 4.7.2 the switch `-Wall` I get the following warning:

```
warning: variable ‘tables’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
```

I know is not a problem but why it appears? Look illogical:

```
const unsigned char *tables;
char *loc = setlocale(LC_ALL, 0);
setlocale(LC_ALL, loc);
tables = pcre_maketables();
```

my variable is SET and is USED. Any idea?

Comment: I don't see, where it is used, besides the assignment.

Comment: You only assign something to it (you set it). But you don't use it for anything, so gcc wonders why you bother to assign to it if you're not going to do something with it.

Comment: Assign the variable `tables` to NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the compiler perspective, there is no difference of behavior between:

```
const unsigned char *tables;
char *loc = setlocale(LC_ALL, 0);
setlocale(LC_ALL, loc);
tables = pcre_maketables();
```

and

```
char *loc = setlocale(LC_ALL, 0);
setlocale(LC_ALL, loc);
pcre_maketables();
```

The compiler will optimize out the assignment and translate the latter.

Comment: I got it. I will just use the function.

Comment: I forgot I have set it up to further use it with `pcre_exec` then I just used `0` as `default character tables`